# Image with Content-Type: binary/octet-stream being saved with wrong format

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, mime-types, content-type

I am using wp_upload_bits which is a cURL wrapper for WordPress for saving in my server a remote .png image, which was previously downloaded with Content-Type: binary/octet-stream.

This is how my code looks like:

**(wrong code, see the one underneath)**

```
    //File contents
    $attachment = 'image/png,' . file_get_contents( $url );

    // Upload bits attachment
    $result = wp_upload_bits( 
        basename( $url ), 
        null,
        $attachment
    );
```

**(right code)**

```
    $attachment = new WP_Http();
    $attachment = $attachment->request( $url, array(
        'headers' => array( 
            'X-app-action' => 'importing'
        ),
    ) );

    // Upload bits attachment
    $result = wp_upload_bits( 
        basename( $url ), 
        null,
        $attachment[ 'body' ]
    );
```

**EDITED:** This is actually the code, I got confused, I am using WP_Http() instead of file_get_contents()

Unfortunately, I have to assume that the image is being saved with the wrong format, since it looks kind of corrupted or broken, the image won't show up at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$attachment` should only contain `file_get_contents( $url )`, the filetype is checked internally by filename so make sure you have the correct path.

Comment: @Xorifelse Apologies, I got confused, I am using WP_Http() instead of file_get_contents(), I edited the code in the question.

Comment: Perhaps test and add the header to `image/png` (if it is a png image), if it works fetch the correct mime-type by using `wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes )` where `$mimes` holds the correct mimetype. But just saying, there might be another way, never used WP in my life..

Comment: Shall I add the header `image/png` within the WP_Http request object?

Comment: @Xorifelse I did try adding, `'Content-Type' => 'image/png'`, but the image still seems corrupt.